# generate a signed apk error

Tags: android, android-studio, apk

Recently I downloaded a source code of a game. I changed all (package name, images, etc.). When I want to generate the .apk, this error pop on : [image: error]

This is my build.gradle configuration : [image: config]

So please, if you have the answer,guide me step by step to solve this problem.

Comment: The message is telling you what to do. You have to migrate your java keystore with given command in the exceptiontext. see https://petersekera.eu/migrate-jks-keystore-from-unity-android-project-to-pkcs12-format/

Comment: Thank u so much Jérôme. the link that u put is so helpfull